# How can I find out the needed sample size

Tags: nonparametric, sample-size, paired-data

I'm going to study if medical reconciliation diminishes the amount of inappropriate medications amongst elderly people in a small part of Sweden.
I will count the number of inappropriate medications before and after medical reconciliation. There are no data on the amount of inappropriate medication in this group. I want to do a Wilcoxon ranksumtest and have decided a significant diminution to 10% with the power of 80%.
1-How do I calculate the sample size?

It will be a paired analyses before and after with an nonparametric test. I don't find a suitable calculator since I have no data.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [G*Power](http://www.gpower.hhu.de/en.html)? It can calculate the required sample size to achieve certain power, given the level of significance, and the effect size you want to be able detect. I did a quick calculation using the information you provided and it seems that for a relatively small effect size of 0.3 you would require a total sample size of N=54. If I were you I would download it though and would play a bit with the parameters.